# Display Model records in a dynamic table at view

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

This is My view.

```
<table>
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName)
            <br>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseSubject)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to display results in a table. But it can have maximum 3 columns.Suppose model returns 7 records and those will display in columns and 3 rows table.Last row has just 1column.So table should be dynamically change to number of records. How can i do this.

Comment: did you find your answer ? Use <tr> inside for loop and enclose each DisplayFor inside for loop with <td>

Comment: not yet. Any help please.

Comment: I'm not able to answer since this question was marked as duplicate so I'm posting the code in comment
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
     <tr>   <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName)
        </td><td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseSubject)
        </td></tr>
    }

Comment: @Anand, This generates 7 rows if there are 7 records - not what OP has asked for (3 rows containing 2 records and the last row with one) Look at the duplicate

Comment: I tried it. but i still failed to get expecting output. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880025/display-records-in-table-with-fixed-number-of-columns
this is it. can u show me where I made wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I haven't read the question clearly